Bulk Table export as DDL separated files in DBeaver
I am trying to export and entire database's schemas for tables, views, etc.
I must export the schemas as SQL individual files.
I've been doing it manually through the option generate SQL-> DDL but this seems inefficient and there are a lot of objects so im not gonna end like ever.
Im using DBeaver with postgre.

See the manual: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data.html#change-output-settings-of-the-sql-generator

That doesn't look like a question related to software development. Why do you use a GUI tool for that?

@LaurenzAlbe well it kind of is related I guess, since i need to perform a code clean up which requires ensuring the current statements for the DB schemas.
As for why am I am using a GUI i am not really sure how to answer, I guess because it facilitates the DB management from a server origin just as MYSQL does.
Even thought i am asking about DBeaver if there is other way to migrate the schemas to sql statements separated per file I would be more than willing to hear it.

If you want to automatize such processing, use a command line tool like pg_dump that you can use in a script rather than a GUI.
